# Array not being created after sending multiple input values with the same name

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to send a few input fields to my PHP file and loop them there so I need them as an array.

These are my input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[3314,99|1 pallet][kuub]" value="1 pallet">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[3314,99|1 pallet][price]" value="31499">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[3314,99|1 pallet][quantity]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[2][price]" value="27999">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[2][quantity]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[70][price]" value="30999">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[70][quantity]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[3624,99|2 pallets][kuub]" value="2 pallets">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[3624,99|2 pallets][price]" value="62499">
<input type="hidden" name="productencheckout[3624,99|2 pallets][quantity]" value="1">
```

And it is posted like this:

```
productencheckout[3314,99|1 pallet][kuub]: 1 pallet
productencheckout[3314,99|1 pallet][price]: 31499
productencheckout[3314,99|1 pallet][quantity]: 1
productencheckout[2][price]: 27999
productencheckout[2][quantity]: 1
productencheckout[70][price]: 30999
productencheckout[70][quantity]: 1
productencheckout[3624,99|2 pallets][kuub]: 2 pallets
productencheckout[3624,99|2 pallets][price]: 62499
productencheckout[3624,99|2 pallets][quantity]: 1
```

So I tried the following:

```
echo $_POST['productencheckout']['3314,99|1 pallet']['kuub'];

$productarr = $_POST['productencheckout'];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($productarr);
echo '</pre>';
```

But it is all empty. Why?

Comment: how did you submitting this form ?

Comment: @twan, I tested it by copy pasting this in a PHP file : https://pastebin.com/raw/QjqA55kN and this is the output : http://prntscr.com/mo2w6r No issues found!

Comment: there is no issue with the code you provided. Can you bit elaborate the code if you still have an issue.

Comment: try this $_POST[];

Comment: @BILALMALIK `$_POST` is empty but for some reason `$_GET` contains everything?? This is my form: `<form id="checkoutform" action="includes/betaal.php" method="post">` Why is everything in `$_GET` if I set the method to post.

Comment: your code is working fine there is no issue! check if form button type is submit